# How to export all PDFs from a Mendeley collection?

Tags: export, citations, mendeley

I am using [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com) as a reference manager and I would like to be able to export the PDFs from a collection to be shared with others.

I work with others who are not as tech savvy, and want to receive all the PDFs in a `.zip` file.

Is it possible to export all the PDFs from Mendeley?

When checking [the official docs](https://service.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27743/supporthub/mendeley/kw/export/#:%7E:text=To%20export%20your%20library%20from%20Mendeley%20Desktop%3A&text=Go%20to%20%27File%27%20and%20click,then%20save%20to%20your%20machine), I can only see the option to export the library in a couple formats that reference the PDFs but do not directly include them.